# How can I find an item with specific value, in a Collection bound to a Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been Google'ing a bit around for this, but without getting any real answer. Probably because my question might be a bit cryptic. Here goes:

Lets say i have an `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>` containing a bunch of models. I then add the corresponding Views to a **Canvas**. Specifying this in the resources of the Window, and then bind the Canvas' `ItemsSource` to the `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>`. This works fine.
SomeModel is bound to SomeView, this is a UserControl.

Now, when this View gets focus, or when I MouseDown on it, I would like to have it marked as "Selected". Somehow, i would like to have a property in the codebehind to the Window holding my Canvas, where i can always get the selected item.

I've been thinking of having a **BindingList** instead of the `ObservableCollection`, and when an `IsSelected` property on the model changes, then a method will extract the selected item from the list. But this seems to be a bit of a performance killer, as i will be notified on all changes to the items.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Oh yeah, and there can't be multiple selected models..

Comment: How do you add the Views to the Canvas?

Comment: In Window.Resources, i define a DataTemplate that specifies DataType "SomeModel" should be shown as SomeUsercontrol. I then bind the Canvas ItemsSource to an `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>` that holds all the Models

Comment: I am confused: [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) doesn't have a `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: Sorry. The Canvas has an ItemsContro, that has an ItemsSource. LIke this: `<Canvas Name="SomeCanvas"> <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeObservableList}" /> </Canvas>`

Comment: @Andreas ListBox is just a spiced up ItemsControl. It has many of the properties that you want. Also you will have runtime errors if you try to put a FrameworkElement decendant in two controls at once. This is because the parent property can only be set once. Not once for the ItemsControl and once for the Canvas. Otherwise you have to clone the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could solve this. But probably the simplest it to work with a ListBox and bind to it. ListBox as it has bindable ItemsSource and a SelectedItem property that has the item that is currently selected in it. It also calls the SelectionChanged event when the selection changes if you want to do something in the code behind .cs file.

I would recommend keeping the ObservableCollection in your View Model to keep true to MVVM.

If the style or placement of ListBox does not suit your override the template to something that suits your needs better.

You could look at a behaviour if the above doesn't work for you but best to keep it simple.

**UPDATE**

This is how you would build the view. Note the ItemsPanel attribute is bound to a defined ItemsPanelTemplate in the UserControl.Resources section which specifies a Canvas to put the items on.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.View1"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:View1Model x:Key="View1ModelDataSource" />
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <Canvas />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>   
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource View1ModelDataSource}}">
    <ListBox Margin="80,85,183,54" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataModelCollection}"/>
</Grid>
```

On the View Model

```
public class View1Model
{
     private ObservableCollection<SomeModel> _DataModelCollection;

     public ObservableCollection<SomeModel> DataModelCollection
     {
        get { return this._DataModelCollection; }
        set { this._DataModelCollection = value; }
     }
 }
```

It should be noted though that Canvas itself does not have any logic to let the user move controls around on it at runtime.

Comment: But i want to show the selectable UserControls on a Canvas, not in a list. Optimally, i would like the ObservableCollection(Or whatever collection suits) to have a SelectedIndex property, that will automatically update if one of its items get their IsSelected property set to true. I understand why you recommend the ListBox, and i have previously used this for another scenario, but now its a canvas...

Comment: Please elaborate why you need to use the Canvas

Comment: The UserControls are on a Canvas, so that the user can arrange them exactly as pleased. They are draggable, but should also be selectable.

Comment: @Andreas If you modify the template of a ListBox Control you can have a Canvas.

Comment: Okay, thanks. i think this is pretty much what im looking for.